# Why does a decompression occur when a hole appears on the fuselage of an aircraft?

Tags: cabin-pressure

I've never understood the mechanics behind explosive decompression and what is has to do with the difference of pressure.

I know the pressure in the cabin is set to a certain point, but don't understand what it has to do with why a vacuum occurs after a hole appears in the fuselage of an aircraft.

Could someone explain to me the mechanics behind this?

Comment: Not a vaccuum, just a very rapid drop to the pressure of the outside atmosphere at that point.  Which in the stratosphere is quite low.  So, the question contains a misconception, but it still can be answered-- I guess this comment could be made into an answer.

Comment: Could you edit your question to clarify where you've searched and what you found already, complete with links and references, and context if applicable? In particular, please let us know what you find missing or unclear about the Wikipedia entry on the topic, if one exists. This allows those who might want to answer to do so without needing to redo the work you've already done.

Comment: Haven't you ever popped open a can of beer?  That sound is higher pressure in the can escaping to lower pressure outside the can.  It is the same idea with a pressurized airplane fuselage, except on a larger scale.  And without the beer...

Comment: @MichaelHall that's an answer right there... now I'm thirsty.... mmmmmm beeeeeeerrrrrr...

Comment: Seriously though, what is the specific question, or concept can you not understand?  Because if you know that airplanes are pressurized, and you understand that there is a pressure differential at altitude, then why wouldn't you instinctively deduce that the pressure would try to equalize when the hull is breached?  Difference in pressure is usually part of the answer, not part of the question...

Comment: Tempted to give an answer reading simply "Because a hole has appeared on the fuselage of an aircraft."

Comment: I am always puzzled by questions where all the information needed to answer the question is contained within the question itself.  And I am downvoting because a full day later the OP still hasn't clarified his/her confusion...

Comment: @MichaelHall  I agree.  "What else do you **think** would happen???"

Comment: Deleting the question is fine, but vandalizing it so that nobody can read what the others are replying to, isn't. They took the time to write replies to you; do them the courtesy of not leaving their answers hanging in limbo, responding to what's no longer visible. Edit rolled back.

Comment: If you believe deleting is fine, then would you kindly do so?

Comment: @Super If you feel it's necessary, you should be able to delete your own question. However, since others have put effort into answering it, it would be considerate to leave it here. Sure, some of the comments weren't the friendliest, however, if you'd followed the advice of CGCampbell and added _your_ background & research and the specifics you didn't understand, then the answers could have been tailored to explain the things _you_ didn't understand, even if they were "obvious" to others.

Comment: Once a question has upvoted answers, it can no longer be deleted by the originator, and this question now has 2 answers with up-votes. Thus, now, deleting isn't the option it once was. The question may possibly be closed, but it will remain for others to search/find later.

Answer (score 1):

Mechanics:

If the air pressure inside the aircraft is **high** enough compared to the pressure outside,
and if a vent between the two is both **large** enough and **created quickly** enough,
then the pressures will equalize (the interior pressure will drop)
more quickly than some structure in the aircraft or in the bodies of those onboard
can handle without serious damage.
Then the decompression might as well be called explosive.

---

Hollywood misconceptions (not a direct answer, so a link suffices instead of a summary):

https://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/ExplosiveDecompression

Answer (score 1):

When a plane is cruising at high altitude, the air pressure outside is much lower than it is at sea level- too low to support life. To prevent the passengers from dying, extra compressed air is pumped into the body of the plane. if a hole appears in the body of the plane, that extra air pressure inside goes rushing out the hole at high speed into the lower air pressure outside.

Comment: How big a hole, and how sudden?  For an airliner at cruise altitude, its outflow valve(s) already provide a hole of about a square foot, to avoid overpressurization.

Comment: @CamilleGoudeseune  The outflow valve is mostly, like 95% or so, closed at cruise.  I've never tried to drive it open at high altitude (I prefer to keep my job), but if you did you'd get a fairly rapid -- although probably not quite "explosive" -- decompression.  Even with the time (many seconds) to drive the outflow valve open, I'd expect that you could dump the cabin pressure in a minute or less.  That's pretty rapid!

Answer (score -1):

Air pressure is the weight of the air in an imaginary column directly above you up to outer space.  Just like the weight of the water above you increases as you scuba dive into the ocean.

Under normal atmospheric conditions, the weight of the air we feel when sitting on a beach at sea level is 14.7 PSI (pounds per square inch).  Which means there is pressure always pushing against your body from the weight of the air around  you.  As you increase your altitude, the weight of the air above you decreases and the pressure you feel decreases.  As a rule of thumb, the air pressure is cut in half every 18,000 FT.  This would mean the air pressure at 18,000 FT is 7.35 PSI.  (The rule of thumb while scuba diving is the water pressure doubles every 33 feet).

As altitude climbs, there may not be enough oxygen for our body to use and we will become hypoxic (hypoxic hypoxia).  Another characteristic of our body is that our blood needs to have a certain amount of air pressure to push the oxygen into the hemoglobin.  If this cannot occur, will will become hypoxic (hypemic hypoxia).  To maintain a healthy air pressure in the airplane, we pressurize the cabin to an altitude that is suitable for both us and the airplane structure.

There is a misconception with the word "vacuum" that many people have.  Vacuum is not the absence of pressure (in this case air pressure) but a lower pressure than the reference pressure.  So, I could be correct to say that I live in a vacuum because the air pressure at 2500 FT MSL is lower than sea level.

The pressure inside the cabin is at a higher pressure than the outside air pressure the airplane is cruising at.  So in essence, the airplane is also flying in a vacuum (as compared to cabin pressure).  When a hole opens up the air will rush out of the cabin causing the air pressure in the cabin to decrease and cabin altitude to rise.  Air **always** flows from high pressure to low pressure.

So when an explosive decompression occurs, the higher cabin pressure will rush out to the lower outside air pressure and a vacuum (with respect to where the cabin air pressure was originally) will form, all persons not on oxygen will become hypoxic if there is not enough oxygen in the air.  If air pressure drops to a much lower value, all persons not on a pressure breathing oxygen mask will become hypoxic.

Comment: Vacuum:  "A space entirely devoid of matter."   You don't live in a vacuum.

Comment: Like I said, there is a misconception on the word "vacuum".  There is no true vacuum.  The definition that I gave it allows the OP to understand the context of what people say when they use that word.  From an engineering standpoint, it is also an accurate definition.

Comment: And I'm not a medical pro, but I'm pretty sure hemoglobin doesn't rely on air pressure to "push" the O2 molecule into it.  Hypoxia occurs because there are simply less molecules at altitude.

Comment: You can look up those terms I provided and see that they are also correct.

Comment: Nobody uses the term vacuum to describe the atmosphere at 2500 feet.  Except you of course.

Comment: I think you are missing the bigger picture and getting hung up on an example.  It is only an example and not how I typically think about the air around me.  I simply live in an area where the air pressure is about 13.41 PSIA.  Sea level pressure is 14.7 PSIA so I have a differential (or vacuum) of 1.29 PSIA.  I can understand that you don't like that example.  What example would you use to describe this?  https://www.engineeringtoolbox.com/air-altitude-density-volume-d_195.html

Comment: Well, I'm surprised nobody else has jumped on this because this is the sort of site where if you used a term like "the vacuum of space" somebody would argue that it isn't a true vacuum.  True enough, but a lot closer than living at 2500'.  So, I looked up a few definitions of vacuum, and "significant" pressure differential is acceptable.  Personally I would reserve vacuum for more extreme cases.  I used to have to go in a hypobaric chamber every 4 years to experience hypoxia.  They would take us up to 25,000 ft.  I would describe this as significant, but would still avoid calling it a vacuum.

Comment: Anyway, I won't debate opinions, I just haven't heard anyone as loose in their interpretation and use of the word before now, and I thought I would offer my perspective in case it helps...

Comment: ...and I'm not sure what you are asking regarding the link to the engineering tool box.  It is just data and graphs showing decreasing pressure and density with altitude.  At some point at the edge of our atmosphere I would consider it a vacuum, but I don't have any real opinion on what the specific criteria should be.